# regex - Replace Linebreak ONLY when they do not have a semicolon

Tags: regex, replace, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to remove all line breaks matching certain criteria. I'm using Visual Studio Code with the following regex pattern.

```
(?!;)\n
```

However, it still selects line breaks that contain a semicolon character before breaking.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `(?!;)\n` = `\n` as LF symbol is not a `;`. Try `(^|[^;])\n` and replace with `$1`.

Comment: Worked as a charm. I replaced it with nothing in order to eliminate those specific linebreaks.

Comment: You must replace with `$1` to keep the chars captured in Group 1.

Answer (score 0):

The `(?!;)` is a negative lookahead that "restricts" the following `\n` pattern to not match a `;` - and it is always true since an LF symbol is not a `;`. Hence, `(?!;)\n` is equal to `\n`, and it matches any LF char.

You may use

```
(^|[^;])\n
```

and replace with `$1` to restore the char captured with `(^|[^;])` pattern (start of a line (`^`) or (`|`) any char but `;` (`[^;]`)) in the resulting text.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need

Find `\n(?<!;\n)`
Replace with nothing.

Sample

```
asdf
;
asdf
adsfasdf;
;
;
```

Benchmark

```
Regex1:   (^|[^;])\n
Options:  < none >,  Newline only
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   2
Elapsed Time:    0.43 s,   430.78 ms,   430778 µs
Matches per sec:   232,138


Regex2:   \n(?<!;\n)
Options:  < none >,  Newline only
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   2
Elapsed Time:    0.15 s,   153.75 ms,   153745 µs
Matches per sec:   650,427
```

*Note - I would not use raw `\n` because

this is rarely the case. If changed to `\r?\n` it covers both

cases. If using dot-net engine, the variable look behind is ok.

If not, you can use `\n(?<!;\n)(?<!;\r\n)` and it still benches better.*

```
Regex3:   \n(?<!;\n)(?<!;\r\n)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   2
Elapsed Time:    0.18 s,   184.67 ms,   184672 µs
Matches per sec:   541,500
```